# PHP CLI with NodeJs

Tags: php, node.js, apache

I have a php application [mostly REST] which runs on top of Apache in a Linux Virtual Machine. This application does a lot of Data queries and i have started having performance issues.

To me one way to address this is using NodeJs Async Patterns. I also plan to implement websockets. But the problem is code size in php is very large. It will take months to rewrite in Node.

Is there a middle ground to complete rewrite. Where i can handle interaction with browser in Node and interaction with database in php cli. and Node can call php cli with approximating Apache environment?

I am using Slim PHP Framework for the REST API, Both HTTP Basic Auth and PHP Sessions, $_GET and variables for extra filters on GET requests. I dont know much about internal workings of Slim. But i think it depends on Apache-PHP implementation of HTTP requests and responses.

How to send the message body [post, put] to the php cli which is in 99% cases JSON (I have file uploads too but which can be ignored as of now). i can have php cli put the json output in STDOUT and parse from there.

The real problem is how to remove dependency on php apache SAPI without changing much of the codebase and how to integrate it with Node. is there any tools, lib which can help in this case.

One more side question, can NGinx help me here somehow?

**Note - My knowledge of node is limited to few fun scripts and custom linting, template compiling, testing scripts for browser side code.

Comment: So you ask about all of this without really indicating where your specific performance bottlenecks are. Do you have performance problems in the database layer? In the web server layer? In the application layer? In the client (browser) layer? What are the specific problems and why do you think rewriting to NodeJS will solve your problems? If you have just toyed around with NodeJS I would strongly question why you think it answers whatever your problems are.

Comment: i main bottleneck is database and memory. IO is really slow on virtual machines. I also wish to implement websocket.

Comment: So if database is your bottleneck, why not start looking for optimizations there?  If memory is bottleneck, why not add more hardware? This is probably a lot cheaper than your engineering time and the cost to rewrite code without any guarantee of seeing an improvement.

Comment: in an ideal scene that's true. But I have a very strict environment. The application is for schools in very remote areas who cant even fund a separate machine for server and hence a virtual machine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you could put nginx in front of Apache. This will allow you to slowly transition your actions to node by routing selectively to one or the other.

Alternatively you could put node in front and use [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy) with express (for exemple) to proxy selectively to Apache. I haven't tried it myself but I guess it should work.

You could also/or use [dnode](https://github.com/substack/dnode) to call php functions from node. [zeromq](http://zeromq.org/) is an option, too.

Comment: finally at least someone is willing to discuss :P. i have already started researching more on dnode as i am implementing some form of websocket comm as well.

Comment: but rather thn going into proxy mechanisms i was thinking if php CLI can help.

Comment: If your goal is to remove Apache, you can use php-fpm behind nginx. I wouldn't go the CLI route but if you will, maybe try with the php-cgi binary as the shebang and the node [cgi](https://npmjs.org/package/cgi) package.

Comment: sure thing. php-fpm behind nginx is my first goal. will work from there onwards.

Comment: You may already have thought about this but some caching in your DB layer might help lower the load.

Comment: i have memcache and file based caching. but it wont cut it.